# list only folders (ls -d) relative to parent in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have found that this command works correctly in the current folder:

```
ls -d */ -1
```

but how can I get the same result in case when I want to list only folders being not in this folder (e.g. I want to list folders being on 1 or 2 levels higher, that is, in a parent or grandparent).

Comment: `ls -d */*/` is a valid command (though hopefully you aren't trying to use its output programatically; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: I meant to make ls from parent folder.

Comment: `(cd .. && exec ls -d */)`? (The `exec` balances out the cost of creating the subshell by consuming it to avoid a fork).

Comment: ...though if you just want to iterate over sibling directories, you don't need and shouldn't use `ls` at all. `for dir in ../*/; do ...`

Comment: I think that (cd /dir && exec ls -d */) is the best option so far. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I'm only avoiding adding it as an answer because, frankly, I like Tom's answer a lot; if there are specific reasons it doesn't work for you (for instance, if you don't want the `../` prepended to output), you might comment on the answer with those reasons, since those issues can be worked around with a slightly different `find` invocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `find`, along with the `-type d` switch to limit the results to directories:

```
find .. -type d
```

You can use `..` to start from the parent directory.

Depending on your version of `find`, you may be able to specify `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` to limit the results:

```
find .. -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d
```

Comment: Isn't it convention to put `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` (like other filters that are global rather than applied only at a given position) first?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that convention but it seems reasonable, will edit.

Comment: Some versions of GNU find would warn on stderr if they were found in other positions; I'm not sure when that behavior started or stopped.

Comment: BTW, from comments on the question, it looks like the OP actually meant it when they said "higher" (wanting to look for directories contained in a parent or grandparent).